# HTTPS does not work - Secure and Non secure data on web page?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https

I have a browser compatibilty problem with https? I have SSL installed and is in usage. Until today morning, my https part is working well. From then, Https is shown as https(with slashed in red color) saying the page has some insecure content. 
I have not changed any code and suddenly i see this problem in chrome. In IE 8, i see the same problem but on every page, it shows me a popup if i should allow to opne secure and non secure or just secure. Firefox has no issues . It shows correct https without any problem.  I am fed up with it searching all over. Why is this happenening for me in Chrome and IE 8. 
Could someone tell me what the problem is and what can be done to solve it!

PS: I have also checked if the page source is any different when IE8 showed with and without secure data. Everything is the same. but viewstateID was different. Is that something that is creating this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have any iframes in your source that are initiliazed without a "src" attribute?  I know this has caused problems for IE, but I don't know about chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by having the absolute path to a resource specified somewhere on the page without having https specified, eg:

```
<img src="http://someurl.com/image.png">
```

If it's a link to something on your site, use https: or a relative path.

Comment: I had a javascript used in the masterpage. It calls unitpngfix, which is used for aligning images,etc for IE 6.And it does not allow you to show pages securely if javascript:void(0) is used inside it. Instead i deleted that part. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ram, I got stuck in the same issue while using the unipngfix.

Answer (score 1):

DO you have any 3:rd party javascript included, like google analytics or other that might have changed.

If you try with Firefox there is firebug you can add as an addon.

In there is a tab for network (net).

It lists everything the page loads.

In that list you should be able to find anything that gets loaded without https.

Answer (score 0):

IE (correctly) complains when there is mixed http/https content as a security warning. Most other browsers do not typically complain when dealing with mixed content so your source is very likely the same in both instances.

I would second David Mårtensson's answer and say the issue is likely a third party library (google or MS hosted JQuery for example) or static asset server.